# What does "deallocated bytearray object has exported buffers" mean exactly

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run an encryption algorithm using AES256 but i get this error instead:
"deallocated bytearray object has exported buffers"

I can't seem to find any proper explanation on what the error itself actually means and therefore am having trouble debugging this. Can anyone explain?

For context, this seems to happen particularly for large files over 1GB

```
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirPath):
    for name in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(root, name)
        with open(filePath, 'rb') as _file:
            textStr = _file.read()

        encrypted = fernet.encrypt(textStr)

        with open(filePath, 'wb') as _file:
            _file.write(encrypted)
```

The above code is me trying to encrypt all files in a directory

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to [the buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), a way of making views of raw memory in Python. It's not frequently used at the Python layer, instead usually being seen in CPython C modules, both built-in and third party C extension modules. The easiest way to use it from Python itself is with [the `memoryview` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview).

My guess is that something in the code (yours or the module you're using) made a view of a `bytearray` object as a buffer, then decref-ed the `bytearray` to zero references before releasing the buffer.

Comment: The library i'm using here is cryptography.fernet. https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/fernet/
Do you happen to know what the issue could be here?

Comment: @ImNotAnIdiotIswear: There are a bazillion ways it could be going wrong; you need to provide a [MCVE] to have a chance of identifying the cause.

Comment: Added the block of code that causes the issue. Once again, only happens with files larger than 1GB

Comment: @ImNotAnIdiotIswear: Nothing obviously wrong. Is there a Traceback to narrow the point of failure? How much RAM do you have? Are you on a 32 bit or 64 bit system? My suspicion would be that you're hitting an out-of-memory condition of some sort with the large files (the docs [note limitations with regard to large files](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#limitations); 1+ GB is often in the problematic range), and the exception handling code path in the library is buggy, causing the broken code path to execute. You may need to go lower level to allow piecemeal encryption of large files.

Comment: I am on a 64bit system. Ah, i see. I'd probably need to do a lot more reading to figure out how to do a piecemeal encryption in that case. Thanks alot for your help!